# MS Access query code in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run a query on an Access DB, I'm used to SQL queries but this doesn't seem to be working the same way. Here's my query:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connect;
command.CommandText = "SELECT RecordID, TimeStamp, EmployeeName, AreaDescription       FROM LoginRecords r, Employees e, Areas a WHERE((e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID) && (a.AreaID =r.AreaID) && (TimeStamp > startDate AND < endDate)) ORDER BY TimeStamp;"
```

I can't seem to get this to run but technically from a SQL standpoint this should be a good query.  The tables are LoginRecords, Employees, Areas.  I can load the tables if that would be helpful.  I appreciate any feedback as to why this won't work in Access.  And startDate and endDate are variables from user input boxes.

Comment: *"this doesn't seem to be working the same way"* - *"can't seem to get this to run"* - Are there any errors?  What is your indication that it isn't working?

Comment: It says missing expression on the command.CommandText when command.Execute() is run.

Comment: @Verber: It's just a guess, but this doesn't look right: `(TimeStamp > startDate AND < endDate)`.  Unless MS Access has weird SQL syntax parsing, that doesn't look very structured.  The overall mix of `AND` and `&&` probably isn't good either.  Maybe stick with one (`AND`) and be more explicit in that parenthetical statement, something like: `(TimeStamp > startDate AND TimeStamp < endDate)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

This is `SQL-92`

```
SELECT      RecordID, 
            TimeStamp, 
            EmployeeName, 
            AreaDescription       
FROM        LoginRecords r
                INNER JOIN Employees e
                    ON e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID
                INNER JOIN Areas a 
                    ON a.AreaID = r.AreaID
WHERE   TimeStamp > startDate AND
        TimeStamp < endDate
ORDER BY TimeStamp;
```

Use `SQL-92` format rather `SQL-89` format because `SQL-89` (*aside from old style*) is prone to going `CROSS JOIN` if not handled correctly.

and this is `SQL-89`

```
SELECT      RecordID, 
            TimeStamp, 
            EmployeeName, 
            AreaDescription       
FROM        LoginRecords r, Employees e, Areas a
WHERE   (e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID) AND
        (a.AreaID = r.AreaID) AND
        (TimeStamp > @startDate AND
         TimeStamp < @endDate)
ORDER BY TimeStamp;
```

MSACCESS: **[INNER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx)**, **[OUTER JOIN (LEFT and RIGHT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx)**

Comment: I'm getting the error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID INNER JOIN Areas a ON a.AreaID = r.AreaI'.
I'm not sure if Access has a different syntax...I can't find anything about coding a query on MSDN.  They just give a few super simple examples but nothing with joins or anything like that.

Comment: @Verber what version of ms access you are using?

Comment: @Verber seeing you comment above, can you show us some code of your ado?

Comment: @Verber you code is fine even though it needs proper object handling and error trapping, the only problem is the error on your syntax. It seems fine with me. seeing your connection string, you are using `MSAccess 2010` right?

Comment: Yes 2010.  Now with you're updated query I'm seeing: No value given for one or more required parameters-that's on the OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: did you specify value for the `startDate` and `endDate`? I'll update the code.

Comment: @Verber try adding this in you `c#` code `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", date1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", date2);` then add `@` on `startDate` and `endDate` inside your query

Comment: Now that's working.  The only problem now is that it's not selecting rows all the way to the @endDate, it stops after two days.  I'll play around with it and see if I can figure out the problem.  Perhaps I need to remove the white space from the datepicker.text element.  Thanks for the help!